# Gap report builder , No text between

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

[Gap table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rBCQ.png)

[design table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VisII.png)

I have a gap between my subtotal and the following line
do you guys have any ideas ?
I have tried almost every parameters

Comment: only seems to be for groups with a `closedate` value. I suspect the close date is longer than it looks, might contain special characters etc. What datatype is close date? You could try trimming it first `TRIM(Fields!closedate.Value)` or try removing it and prove that it is this column that is causing the issue

Comment: ok I will have a look thanks :)

Comment: however it doesn't change anything

Comment: still the problem with that column removed? I would make a copy of the report and start removing things until the gaps disappear, just to narrow it down.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks